# phpMyAdmin no longer notifying me of updates

Tags: phpmyadmin

I'm used to seeing phpMyAdmin notify me of updates fairly frequently so when a few weeks went by without any notifications I headed over to the official site to discover that my installation was out of date.

What I can't determine is why the notifications stopped. I looked in my logs and it appears as if the version checking is still occurring:

> [28/Sep/2015:12:31:00 -0400] "GET /pma/version_check.php?&_nocache=1443457870977619155 HTTP/1.1" 200 2

Yet no notifications are appearing. If I run version_check.php directly, I get a reply of `[]`. On another server that we have (which updated properly), I get `{"version":"","date":""}`.

My config file consists of:

```
$i = 0;
$i++;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = '127.0.0.1';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['port'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['socket'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';

$cfg['ForceSSL'] = true;
$cfg['DefaultLang'] = 'en';
$cfg['ServerDefault'] = 1;
$cfg['PmaNoRelation_DisableWarning'] = true;
$cfg['VersionCheck'] = true;
```

What can I do to get the notification working again?

Comment: What version are you running?

Comment: 4.4.14.1 currently

Comment: I think you should [submit an issue on GitHub](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/new).

Comment: @KennyEvitt It's obvious that you want the OP to do this *your way*, please give them the freedom of doing what they want and don't try and force them. You've already suggested that they submit an issue to GitHub, end of.

Comment: [I submitted an issue for this.](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11713)

Comment: [A comment](https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11713#issuecomment-161899797) on the GitHub issue suggests that your phpMyAdmin host might not have internet access, the proxy it uses is not setup, or that the version check is otherwise being blocked on the network.

Comment: @KennyEvitt Thanks for that. And yes, the server it's on has Internet access.

Comment: @j08691 How about the two other parts of the question (proxy? version check blocked on the network?)  Also, have you tried the latest stable version which is 4.5.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

Most likely this is is caused by missing curl extension and disabled `allow_url_fopen`. Without these phpMyAdmin can not check for new version and doesn't report this anyhow. This will be fixed in future releases, see https://github.com/phpmyadmin/phpmyadmin/issues/11874

Comment: Just did a quick `phpinfo()` and got `cURL support enabled` and `allow_url_fopen On On`